# Mob farm isn't dark, how to fix that?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing on my Switch and I built this mob farm with no access points for light to come through but now it's still bright inside - like torch bright. I'm not using any mods or shaders. The brightness is fluctuating with that of the outside like the sun is in the room. What do I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

it could be the material you used, eg. glass.
also sometimes the world can glitch and appear light or dark in spots it shouldn’t be. if thats the case, log out and relog or worst case scenario, you may have to restart. (or maybe copy the world.)

Comment: thanks but I figured it out. there was light glitched out inside of the cobblestone blocks I used to build it. I had to replace the certain blocks containing light and it reset them to act normal

Comment: so that was a glitch